# ¿ como encriptar un campo con md5 en una aplicacion usando react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, md5

Buenas, actualmente me encuentro desarrollando una app y tengo la necesidad de encriptar el pass ingresado por el usuario con md5 para despues enviarlo a un api guardado en un servidor, la app la estoy realizando con react-native pero al buscar en google solo encuentro librerias para exportarlo a un php y no estoy seguro si puedo utilizar PHP.js que tiene esa funcion, con react-native ( o si siquiera es compatible )

Comment: Hola Alberto José, bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 

conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 

[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a 

tu pregunta, te sugiero modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad 

requerida en el sitio, esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la 

comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, para esto **es muy importante 

leer [ask]**, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun la pagina de `npm` puedes utilizar la siguiente **[libreria](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-md5)** de esta manera

> npm install react-native-md5 --save

*Esto tienes que correrlo en la consola de tu sistema operativo*

> import EventEmitter from "react-native-md5";

*Esto es para importar la libreria a tu proyecto*

Este seria un ejemplo como utilizarlo:

```
import md5 from "react-native-md5";

componentWillMount() {

    let hex_md5v = md5.hex_md5( Date.now() +"" );
    console.log(">>>>hex_md5:", hex_md5v);

    let b64_md5v = md5.b64_md5( Date.now() +"" );
    console.log(">>>>b64_md5:", b64_md5v);

    let str_md5v = md5.str_md5( Date.now() +"" );
    console.log(">>>>str_md5:", str_md5v);

    let hex_hmac_md5v = md5.hex_hmac_md5("my_key", Date.now() +"" );
    console.log(">>>>hex_hmac_md5:", hex_hmac_md5v);

    let b64_hmac_md5v = md5.b64_hmac_md5("my_key", Date.now() +"" );
    console.log(">>>>b64_hmac_md5:", b64_hmac_md5v);

    let str_hmac_md5v = md5.str_hmac_md5("my_key", Date.now() +"" );
    console.log(">>>>str_hmac_md5:", str_hmac_md5v);

}
```